# Access attributes of associated models in Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, ransack

I have a dashboard that shows results fetched from users and nannies model.

In my user.rb, I have

```
User has_many :nannies
```

The nanny.rb has

```
Nanny belongs_to :user
```

User has some basic attributes (name, email, phone etc)
Nanny has other attributes (gender, hours, days etc)
Right now, I have these lines to implement Ransack and fetch users according to filters. The index method of the controller is

```
@users = User.ransack(params[:q])
@people = @users.result
```

I can filter out the results based on attributes from Nanny. The filter form in the view is like this

```
<%= search_form_for @users do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :firstname_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :firstname_cont %> 

  <%= f.label :lastname_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :lastname_cont %>

  <%= f.label :role_eq %>
  <%= f.search_field :role_eq %>

  <%= f.label :nannies_gender_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :nannies_gender_cont %>

  <%= f.label :nannies_hours_eq %>
  <%= f.search_field :nannies_hours_eq %>

 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The results are displayed like this

```
    <% @people.each do |test| %>
      <%= test.id %>
      <%= test.firstname %>
      <%= test.email %>
      <%= test.hours %>
    <% end %>
```

I am getting an error 'undefined method hours for User' (which obviously belongs to the Nanny model).

I need to be able to achieve the following

1. Load all Users and its associated Nannies
2. Run Ransack and filter out the results
3. Display all attributes from all associated models in the view

Would really appreciate any guidance/correction in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your question is how to fix `undefined method hours for User`:

The following solution is not really a Ransack "thing", but more just a Rails "thing":

```
<% @people.each do |test| %>
  <%= test.id %>
  <%= test.firstname %>
  <%= test.email %>
  <% test.nannies.each do |nanny| %>
    <%= nanny.hours %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

- You need to loop through each `nanny` that belongs to `test` (of which is a `User` record), and from there only when you can access `hours` value for each `nanny`

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.